# Action Class not getting called when doing Search through JQ Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 2.0 web application where there few buttons whose onclick i call a action method, but when i press search button for the first time , the action method is called but after that if i try to click the search button the action method is not getting called.

Also let me tell you that i am using the JQ Grid to display the data on button onclick.
Please see below code snippet.

function LoadGrid(data, type) {

```
        var showGrid = $("#showGrid");
        var navigation = $("#navigation");

        showGrid.jqGrid({
            url: '/Customer/CustomerSearchInfo',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            postData: { param: data, type: type },

            colNames: ['Customer Name', 'Contact Name', 'Company Number', 'Customer Number', 'Link Number', 'Phone', 'SalesRep Name', 'Sequence'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'COMPANY_NAME', index: '1', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'CONTACT_NAME', index: '2', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'COMPANY_NUM', index: '3', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'CUSTOMER_NUM', index: '4', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'LINK_NUM', index: '5', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'PHONE_1', index: '6', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'SALESREP_NUM', index: '7', align: 'left', sortable: true },
              { name: 'ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM', index: '8', align: 'left', sortable: true }
             ],
            pager: navigation,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30, 50],
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: '',
            height: '250px',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            sortname: '0',
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autowidth: true,
             }
        })

    };
```

The action method mentioned (/Customer/CustomerSearchInfo) is not getting called for the second time.

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult CustomerSearchInfo(string param, int type)
        {

```
        try
        {
            var custInfo = new List<Customer>();
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(customerID: param);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(customerName: param);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(contactName: param);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(companyID: param);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(salesRepID: param);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(phone: param);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(addrtype: param);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(status: param);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    custInfo = custDO.GetCustomerInfo(linkID: param);
                    break;
            }

                            return custInfo != null
                       ? Json(GetJson(custInfo, 10, custInfo.Count, 0),
                              JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
                       : Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }


    }
```

For reference below are the 2 search buttons:

input id="btnCustID" type="button" class="buttonsearch" title="Search BY Customer ID"
                    onclick="LoadGrid(document.getElementById('txtCustID').value,1)"

input id="btnCustName" type="button" class="buttonsearch" title="Search BY Customer Name"
                    onclick="LoadGrid(document.getElementById('txtCustName').value,2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript will not work, because you are trying to reinitialize already initialized jqGrid. There are few things you can do.

You can unload your jqGrid before initializing it again (you need to mark Custom checkbox when downloading the grid):

```
var showGrid = $("#showGrid");
var navigation = $("#navigation");

showGrid.jqGrid('GridUnload');
...
```

You can just change postData and reload your jqGrid without reinitialization (you need to initialize it earlier):

```
var showGrid = $("#showGrid");
showGrid.setPostData({ param: data, type: type });         
showGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Or you can implement native jqGrid searching, here you have some simple description: http://tpeczek.com/2009/11/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-searching.html

Comment: thanks tpeczek it solved my problem, but one more concern is there is that while for the second time search the data is getting reflected but i want that it sholud clear the previous values in the text boxes (search fields) also which are present in that page. Is there any property of the jq grid that does that or do we need to clear the text box values indivisually for every text box present.

Comment: Add those to your script after setting jqgrid postData: $('#txtCustID').val(''); $('#txtCustName').val('');

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what's really going on; for starters: is a request made that second time? And what does it look like?

Comment: yes for the second time it's not calling the action class, even in the debug mode it's not getting hit.